# Customize ribbon \ Choose commands from: Macros \ lists dead procedures

Tags: excel, vba, customization, ribbon

I have developed an Excel Add-In, mainly for my personal use.  I have added buttons to the ribbon to fire the macros.  I feel my add-in is much more mature now than when I first started into this.  It's to the point where I'd like to share the add-in with a colleague.

Here's my issue; I want it to be clearly communicate the macros that need to be linked to ribbon buttons.  The first picture shows what I intend to have, procedures listed with the "CustomAddIn_" prefix.

The second picture shows what I cannot figure out... there are also procedures listed here that no longer exist in the add-in (have been commented out or removed altogether).  I see that these are prefixed with a '.  Any ideas what's going on here?  I would like to remove these from the "Choose commands from \ Macros" list box.

Thanks!

[Screen Grab - Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5AFK.jpg)

Comment: How do these macros show up in that list in the first place?

Comment: They've been available there since I "added" my add-in through the Developer \ Add-Ins menu. It's reading subs from my add-in, which is exactly what I wanted. But there are these "obsolete" subs that appear in the list that are no longer in the Add-In.  I've tried removing the add-in then re-establishing it (with closing and re-opening excel at the right times). Still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question a little while back and feel I owe an update to future readers.  I wasn't ever able to replicate the problem but David's answer got me to a solution:

Since the error seemed to be related to some kind of copy of the add-in file (my own doing at some point), I completely recreated the add-in.  I copied all the code out of the modules into notepad files, added modules into a new excel file, copied in the code then drag and dropped the userforms from one project to another.  Saved as xlam. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the list of macros that appears when you select:
File>Options>Customize Ribbon>Macros...

Rather than adding them this way, You can add them to your Add-In code. As such they only appear in the Add-in menu if the user has the add-in open.

It also means if you have many add-ins each one adds/removes it's own set of buttons. So here's what my add-ins menu currently looks like:

[image]

And here is the code I use to create this buttons.  So add this code to each of your add-in files.  You just need to call `AddToolbarButton` in the `Auto_Open` for each button you need to create.

```
Option Explicit
'/*libdesc*/Create our toolbar when loaded, remove it when we're closed...

Private Const TOOLBAR_NAME      As String = "{Free text Toolbar Name}"

Sub Auto_Open()
  ' In some instances of Excel, the MacroOptions call provokes an error about "hidden workbooks"
  ' so the on error handler avoid that (the call seems to still work strangely enough)
  On Error Resume Next
  ' faceid 422 is a small graph... looks a bit like curves, see also 418
  ' faceid 107 is a table with a lightning bolt - seems OK ....
  ' faceid 2170 is somethign with colours ...
  ' See http://www.outlookexchange.com/articles/toddwalker/images/icons1-500.jpg
  ' http://www.outlookexchange.com/articles/toddwalker/BuiltInOLKIcons.asp
  AddToolbarButton TOOLBAR_NAME, "{Name of Macro here}", 3865, "Button title that will appear in Toolbar", _
                  "The hoover description (Excel toolbar item text) for this button"

End Sub

Sub Auto_Close()
  On Error Resume Next
  DeleteToolbar TOOLBAR_NAME
End Sub

Function AddToolbarButton(cmdbarname As String, _
                          Optional handler As String = "", _
                          Optional btnIconFace As Integer = -1, _
                          Optional btnCaption As String = "", _
                          Optional btnTip As String = "") As Button
  Dim prevDisp As Boolean: prevDisp = Application.DisplayAlerts
  Dim cmdbar As CommandBar
  Dim btn As CommandBarButton

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  On Error Resume Next

  Set cmdbar = Application.CommandBars(cmdbarname)
  If cmdbar Is Nothing Then
    Set cmdbar = Application.CommandBars.Add(cmdbarname)
    If Not cmdbar Is Nothing Then
      cmdbar.Visible = True
      cmdbar.Position = msoBarTop
    End If
  End If
  '/*link*/Icon Codes,http://supportingtech.blogspot.com/2011/03/microsoft-faceid-numbers-for-vba.html
  '/*link*/Excel Icon use by ribbon,http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;[LN];Q213552
  If handler <> "" And Not cmdbar Is Nothing Then
    Set btn = cmdbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    If Not btn Is Nothing Then
      btn.OnAction = handler

      If btnIconFace >= 0 Then
        btn.Style = IIf(btnCaption = "", msoButtonIcon, msoButtonIconAndCaption)
        btn.FaceId = btnIconFace
      ElseIf btnCaption <> "" Then
        btn.Style = msoButtonCaption
      End If
      If btnCaption <> "" Then
        btn.Caption = btnCaption
      End If

      btn.DescriptionText = IIf(btnTip = "", handler, btnTip)
      btn.TooltipText = IIf(btnTip = "", handler, btnTip)
    End If
    Set AddToolbarButton = btn
  End If

  Application.DisplayAlerts = prevDisp

End Function

Function DeleteToolbar(cmdbarname As String)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim cmdbar As CommandBar
  Set cmdbar = Application.CommandBars(cmdbarname)
  If Not cmdbar Is Nothing Then
    cmdbar.Delete
    Set cmdbar = Nothing
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the code regarding the programmatic approach to the interface customization.  I will definitely be working that in.  Perhaps I wasn't clear with what I am after here, but I would like to REMOVE the invalid macros that are listed in the options menu (yes, the one you described).  I loaded the add-in on a different machine and the problem persists... see the 2nd screen grab I added to the original question.

Comment: I suspect the extra invalid macros (interestingly in an add-in sheet called _Custom Add In - **Copy**_) are from a copy of your sheet.
  Add-Ins can be quite annoying to work with as they hang about even if you haven't added them to your 'Active Application Add-ins' (i.e. they're just an open excel file. Because once you've saved something as an add-in you no longer see it in Excel front end so can't close it, you need to close the session.

Comment: Look in the links of all open sheets ('Data>Edit Links') and see if any of them have links to _Custom Add In - **Copy**.xlam_.  You could try opening a clean Excel session (no other sheets open), create a new sheet and then see if you see all these extra ghost macros.  Also, if you hover over the ghost macros in the Customize...toorbar list it shows you the path of where Excel thinks this macro is.

Comment: Another thing, we work with a lot of Excel add-in here, and as such, we don't hold add-ins in the default location for Excel (c:\...addins). Rather we keep them in a common network location that everyone has read-only access to.  That way if we need to update an add-in we can just replace the existing network version. When users add add-ins we get them answer "No" to the "..copy add-in locally" question.

Comment: We also have a number of add-ins that users DON'T add to their Excel Add-Ins, rather the add-in file sits in the same location as the Excel files that use it, then when the user opens the sheet it automatically opens the add-in as soon as they run a macro (e.g. press a button).